# Tkinter canvas method to display multiple images recursively

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas

I would like to display multiple images in tkinter canvas looping through at some fixed interval. It works fine without recursiveness.

Here's my code so far, appreciate any suggestion.

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

picNames = [f"{x}.png" for x in 'abcd']  # all pics are having equal shape

w, h = (lambda picNames: Image.open(picNames[0]).size)(picNames)  # (640, 640)
lag = 2000

# make GUI
tk = Tk()
tk.title('chessGUI')

canvas = Canvas(tk, width=w, height=h, highlightthickness=0, borderwidth=0)
canvas.grid()

bg_col = 'gray15'
canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, w, h, fill=bg_col, outline=bg_col)
canvas.config(cursor='tcross')

# main loop
picNameIterator = (x for x in picNames)


def update_ip():
    global picNameIterator

    try:
        picName = next(picNameIterator)
        img = Image.open(picName).resize((w, h))
        img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)

        canvas.create_image(w // 2, h // 2, image=img, anchor=CENTER)

        tk.after(int(lag), update_ip)
        # canvas.delete("all")

    except StopIteration:
        picNameIterator = (x for x in picNames)
        update_ip()


update_ip()
tk.attributes('-topmost', True)  # make canvas always on top window
tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: You didn't state clearly what your problem is.

Comment: Always keep a global reference to thinter images.

Comment: Also you can use `itertools.cycle` to create a cycle list instead of normal iterator, then you don't need to use `try/except`.

Comment: @acw1668 problem is I am not able to display multi images recursively

Comment: @hussic didn't understand, sorry

Comment: @acw1668 yes, that could be an option, but won't solve the issue here. I will explore to keep canvas intact and use canvas.itemconfigure to change different images. I have done such to change text, not images.

Comment: I don't understand what *"display multi images recursively"* means actually.  As @hussic said, you need to save a reference of the image otherwise you will have the same issue of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16424091/why-does-tkinter-image-not-show-up-if-created-in-a-function).

Comment: Thanks for your direction. What I meant is display multiple images one after another.

Comment: You code works fine after adding `global img` (to avoid the image being garbage collected) inside `update_ip()`.  However it is better to create the canvas image item outside the function and then update its image inside the function.

Comment: Oh yea, thousand thanks Sir!